# C++ syntax Problem : how function is pass as parameter

Tags: c++

I am not understanding the function passing in the accumulate function

```
int numIdenticalPairs(vector<int>& A) {
        return accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0, [count = unordered_map<int, int> {}] (auto a, auto b) mutable {
            return a + count[b]++;
        });
    }
```

Comment: what exactly you have trouble with? Please be specific in what you understand and what not from the code snippet so that we can help you.

Comment: I am not understanding the how ''mutable" function is pass  "[count = unordered_map<int, int> {}]" this syntaxt

Answer (score 0):

`std::accumulate()` function is used to accumulate all the values in the range `[first, last]` both inclusive to any variable `initial_sum`.

```cpp
int myfunction (int x, int y) {
  return x+2*y;
}

int main () {
  int init = 100;
  int numbers[] = {10, 20, 30};
  std::cout << std::accumulate (numbers, numbers+3, init, myfunction);

}
```

and 4th parameter where you are confused is [lambda function of c++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp#:%7E:text=In%20C%2B%2B11%20and%20later%2C%20a%20lambda%20expression%E2%80%94often%20called,that%20are%20passed%20to%20algorithms%20or%20asynchronous%20methods.) is same as usual function but has no name.

```
[count = unordered_map<int, int> {}] (auto a, auto b) mutable {
    return a + count[b]++;
};
```

Comment: hey Thanx for help